# file not found selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my problem:

I want to show the picture of a client in a `td`  when the user clicks. Fine, but what happens if there isn't any pic at database? In console, it say that there is no file found. Here is my question:

Is there any kind of selector in jquery or javascript that can be use if there is no file found?

For example, if the pic of an user is not found, show a default pic. Thanks.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Comment: Why not just load the default pic by default and only replace it if there is a pic found in the db?

Comment: How are you loading a picture now? Would be useful to show some of your code so we can make suggestions.

Comment: i select with jquery the id, and append the img src.